# Training in Restricted boltzman machine

Tags: neural-networks, graphical-model, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am having doubt in training part of RBM's. I am confused between whats the difference between training RBM by block gibbs sampling and training RBM using contrastive divergence?

Answer (score 1):

Contrastive divergence is a method by which the gradient of the log-likelihood can be computed for an RBM. Contrastive divergence *uses* gibbs sampling, but it's not just gibbs sampling, and gibbs sampling is used for many things which aren't CD.

Gibbs sampling is a technique for sampling from a distribution whose joint is intractable, but has tractable conditionals (in the case of the RBM, $p(v,h)$ is intractable, but $p(v|h)$ or $p(h|v)$ is).